# Building a database project is not generating a dbschema file

Tags: sql, msbuild, database-project, db-schema, sqlproj

I'm trying to use the `vsdbcmd.exe` command to deploy a SQL DB Project.  However, when I try to build said project using MSBuild, or even in VS (2013), it is not generating a dbschema file (as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833181%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why this might be?  I have permissions in the solution and project directory.  I've tried build, rebuild, `msbuild /t:Build c:\DB\DB.sqlproj`, but I can't see the `.dbschema` file anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong command for the job. You're using either SSDT or the native VS2013 projects. Those generate *.dacpac files (which are glorified zip files and contain the dbschema and other files). You need to use SQLPackage.exe to publish those.

I've got some articles about the SSDT process on my blog: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html

This article in particular likely pertains to your issue: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/11/ssdt-publishing-your-project.html